# Proper way to splice default values into a dataframe using `mutate()` in a function?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

### Background:

My ultimate goal is this json file as specified here: [Trimble Batch Geocoding JSON Spec](https://developer.trimblemaps.com/restful-apis/location/geocoding-api/geocoding-batch/). I reference pieces of that spec as relates to addresses in the hope that it clarifies what I am trying to do.

## Question:

How do I splice in default values from a vector inside a `mutate()`?

### Non-Working Function

I have a function that accepts a dataframe with a variable number of columns.  Some of the columns (represented by `A_dots`) may be different named fields and not always present (e.g. from the Trimble Geocode link:  use "Zip" instead of "StreetAddress"), but there will always be one or more fields, and they are covered by my use of `...` in the function.  There are a handful of other fields (represented by `B, C, D` that ***MAY*** be present in the dataframe (e.g. "GeoList" or "Region"), but most of the time won't be and can be represented by default values as defined in the function's `formals()`.  Here's my **not-working** function, and I know it doesn't work because I don't know how to call the `mutate()` properly to splice in the default values (***which really is my question***):

```
library(tidyverse)  # solution does not need to be tidyverse

myfun <- function(df,
                   ...,
                   B = 4,
                   C = TRUE,
                   D = "a_default_value"){

  vec_field_defaults <- c("B", "C", "D")
  vfd_match <- intersect(vec_field_defaults, names(df))
  vfd_nomatch <- setdiff(vec_field_defaults, names(df))

  if (length(vfd_match) > 0){
    df2 <- df[,vfd_match]
    if (length(vfd_nomatch) > 0){
      df2 <- mutate(df2, !!!vfd_nomatch := !!!vfd_nomatch)  # I need help here
    }
  } else {
    df2 <- data.frame(B = rep(B, nrow(df)),
                      C = rep(C, nrow(df)),
                      D = rep(D, nrow(df)))  # Could this be done better?
  }

  return(df2)
```

## Examples

You only need to read beyond this point if my intent is not clear from above function.

### Baseline Dataframe

Here's a starting dataframe that I'll slice apart for examples below.

```
df_baseline <- data.frame(A = c("Address1", "Address2", "Address3"),
                      B = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
                      C = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
                      D = c("Some", "different", "values."))

> df_baseline
    A_dots B     C         D
1 Address1 1  TRUE      Some
2 Address2 2 FALSE different
3 Address3 3 FALSE   values.
```

### Just the `A_dots` column:

`myfun()` should always drop the `A_dots` column (but keep the number of rows it represents for output!!!) and fill in the default values for `B, C, D` where they are not given in the supplied dataframe:

```
df_1 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots)

> myfun(df_1)
  B    C               D
1 4 TRUE a_default_value
2 4 TRUE a_default_value
3 4 TRUE a_default_value
```

### Keep the `A_dots, B` columns:

```
df_2 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B)

myfun(df_2)  # function breaks, but showing intended output:
  B    C               D
1 1 TRUE a_default_value
2 2 TRUE a_default_value
3 3 TRUE a_default_value
```

### Keep the `A_dots, B, C` columns:

```
df_3 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B, C)

myfun(df_3)  # function breaks, but showing intended output:
  B    C               D
1 1 TRUE  a_default_value
2 2 FALSE a_default_value
3 3 FALSE a_default_value
```

### Keep the `A_dots, B, C, D` columns:

```
df_4 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B, C, D)

myfun(df_4)  # function breaks, but showing intended output:
  B    C     D
1 1 TRUE  Some
2 2 FALSE different
3 3 FALSE values.
```

I think my problem is just how to call the `!!!` for the missing defaults, but I'm not sure, and I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non `tidyverse` approach using `modifyList`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myfun <- function(df, ..., B = 4, C = TRUE, D = "a_default_value") {
  
  vec_field_defaults <- list(B = B, C = C, D = D)
  vec_field_defaults <- lapply(vec_field_defaults, rep, nrow(df))
  vec_field <- modifyList(vec_field_defaults, df)
  
  as.data.frame(vec_field[names(vec_field_defaults)])
}

df_baseline <- data.frame(
  A_dots = c("Address1", "Address2", "Address3"),
  B = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
  C = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  D = c("Some", "different", "values.")
)

df_1 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots)

myfun(df_1)
#>   B    C               D
#> 1 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 3 4 TRUE a_default_value

df_2 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B)

myfun(df_2) 
#>   B    C               D
#> 1 1 TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 2 TRUE a_default_value
#> 3 3 TRUE a_default_value

df_3 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B, C)

myfun(df_3)
#>   B     C               D
#> 1 1  TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 2 FALSE a_default_value
#> 3 3 FALSE a_default_value

df_4 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B, C, D)

myfun(df_4)
#>   B     C         D
#> 1 1  TRUE      Some
#> 2 2 FALSE different
#> 3 3 FALSE   values.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit hacky version that uses rlang::fn_fmls to get a list of the default arguments and uses them.

```r
library(dplyr)

myfun <- function(df,
                  ...,
                  B = 4,
                  C = TRUE,
                  D = "a_default_value"){
  
  vec_field_defaults <- c("B", "C", "D")
  vfd_match <- intersect(vec_field_defaults, names(df))
  vfd_nomatch <- setdiff(vec_field_defaults, names(df))
  # get a named list of the default arguments that are missing
  list_of_needed_defaults <- rlang::fn_fmls()
  list_of_needed_defaults <- list_of_needed_defaults[vfd_nomatch]
  
  if (length(vfd_match) > 0){
    df2 <- df[,vfd_match, drop = FALSE]
    if (length(vfd_nomatch) > 0){
      df2 <- mutate(df2, !!!list_of_needed_defaults)
    }
  } else {
    df2 <- data.frame(B = rep(B, nrow(df)),
                      C = rep(C, nrow(df)),
                      D = rep(D, nrow(df))) 
  }
  
  return(df2)
}

df_baseline <- data.frame(A_dots = c("Address1", "Address2", "Address3"),
                          B = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
                          C = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
                          D = c("Some", "different", "values."))

df_2 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B)
myfun(df_2)
#>   B    C               D
#> 1 1 TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 2 TRUE a_default_value
#> 3 3 TRUE a_default_value
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can create new columns within `mutate` by using a named list. One way to create this list is to use `lapply` over a named vector of columns names and to `get` the default values from the arguments:

`lapply(vec_field_defaults2, \(x) rep(get(x), nrow(df)))`

Where `vec_field_defaults2` is `setNames(vec_field_defaults, nm = vec_field_defaults)`. Alternatively we could use `purrr::set_names(vec_field_defaults)` which automatically names an input vector after itself.

Here is the full code.

```r
library(tidyverse)  # solution does not need to be tidyverse

myfun <- function(df,
                  ...,
                  B = 4,
                  C = TRUE,
                  D = "a_default_value"){
  
  vec_field_defaults <- c("B", "C", "D")
  vec_field_defaults2 <- setNames(vec_field_defaults, nm = vec_field_defaults)
  
  vfd_match <- intersect(vec_field_defaults, names(df))
  
  vfd_nomatch <- setdiff(vec_field_defaults, names(df))
  
  inp_ls <- lapply(vec_field_defaults2,
                \(x) rep(get(x), nrow(df)))
  
  if (length(vfd_match) > 0){
    df2 <- df[,vfd_match, drop = FALSE]
    
    if (length(vfd_nomatch) > 0){
      df2 <- mutate(df2, !!! inp_ls)  # does this help?
    }
    
  } else {
    
    # This isn't much better as the original approach
    inp_ls2 <- lapply(vec_field_defaults2,
                     \(x) rep(get(x), nrow(df)))
    
    df2 <- as.data.frame(inp_ls2)
  }
  
  return(df2)
}


df_baseline <- data.frame(A_dots = c("Address1", "Address2", "Address3"),
                          B = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
                          C = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
                          D = c("Some", "different", "values."))


df_1 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots)

myfun(df_1)
#>   B    C               D
#> 1 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 3 4 TRUE a_default_value

df_2 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B)

myfun(df_2)
#>   B    C               D
#> 1 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 3 4 TRUE a_default_value


df_3 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B, C)

myfun(df_3)
#>   B    C               D
#> 1 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 2 4 TRUE a_default_value
#> 3 4 TRUE a_default_value


df_4 <- select(df_baseline, A_dots, B, C, D)
myfun(df_4)
#>   B     C         D
#> 1 1  TRUE      Some
#> 2 2 FALSE different
#> 3 3 FALSE   values.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>